# Injecting window object into a component into Angular with DI

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm loading socket.io in my application like so:

```
index.html
<script src="http://myapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
...
// Angular stuff
```

I have a component called `Socket` which requires `window.io` to work.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class Socket {

  public isConnected: boolean = false;

  constructor(public events: Events) {
    if (typeof window.io === "undefined") {
        throw new Error("Socket.io is undefined.");
    }

    this.io = window.io;
  }

  connect() {
    this.io.connect("...");
  }

  listen() {

  }

}
```

In theory, it may work (didn't test) but it is not a good practice to inject stuff from window scope into classes.

Is there any way to do it like this:

```
import { SocketIODriver } from 'socket.io';
import { Socket } from 'App/Socket/Socket';

@Component({
   templateUrl: 'layout.html'
})
export class ConferenceApp {
   constructor(
     public io: io,
     public Socket: Socket
   ) {
      this.socket = new Socket(new SocketIODriver());
   }
}
```

Thank you.

Ps. IIRC, socket.io has to be loaded from the server, that's why I load it from my server. If it can be placed into my JS folder, that would be even better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*While this seems to be still working with Angular 8, be cautious, it's an old answer*

Angular > 1 works with injectors. Each injector is scoped to a specific module and **provides** the data you'd like your module to receive.

For example, you can define an object of the shape: `{ useValue: 'theValueToInject' }` and make it available at any level of your tree.

If you want to provide such an object to your module, you will have to rely on the `providers` property of the `@NgModule` decorator. Then you can construct your own object using

`{provide: 'NameToInvoke', useValue: alreadyInitializedValue}`

Since `window` is already an instanciated object, you can rely on this approach to provide it to your module:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: 'Window', useValue: window }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And so, you can use it like :

```js
constructor(@Inject('Window') private window: any) {} // or window type, I don't know what it's exactly
```